# React JS Context API returning undefined values

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am building an e-commerce application with React and am facing some difficulty while passing the data from the global state to the required components.

**Reducer.js**

```
export const reducer = (state, action) => {
    console.log(action.item)
    switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD_TO_CART":
            return {
                ...state,
                cart: [...state.cart, action.item]
            }
        default:
            return state
    }

}

export const initialState = {
    cart: []
}
```

**index.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { StateProvider } from './context/StateProvider';
import { reducer, initialState } from './context/Reducer'

ReactDOM.render(
    <StateProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </StateProvider >,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

***StateProvider.jsx***

```
import { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react"

export const StateContext = createContext()

export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }) => (
    <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
        {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
)

export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext)
```

***Card.jsx***

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { FaStar } from "react-icons/fa";
import { useStateValue } from '../context/StateProvider'

const Card = ({ id, title, price, image, rating }) => {
    const [{ cart }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

    const addToCart = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        dispatch({
            type: 'ADD_TO_CART',
            item: { id, title, price, image, rating }
        })
    }

    return (
        <Container>
            <Image>
                <img src='https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41ezRvTwcaL._AC_SR400,600_.jpg'
                    alt='pic' />
            </Image>
            <Info>
                <h4>Samsung Galaxy S20 FE 5G (Cloud Navy, 8GB RAM, 128GB Storage)</h4>
                <FaStar color='#ff9900' size={25} />
                <p>₹39,990.00</p>
                <button onClick={addToCart}>Add To Cart</button>
            </Info>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Console.log return {id: undefined, title: undefined, price: undefined, image: undefined, rating: undefined}

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like a problem with providing props to Card. Use console.log or debug to check what Card receives as a props.

Comment: Thanks! That is indeed the correct solution. The Home compoenent which inherits the Card should be passing props as well, something I missed

Answer (score 0):

I think its here

```
return {
         ...state,
         cart: [...state.cart, action.payload.item]
        }
```

this also depends on how the item is coming in ?

can you console.log(action) and action.payload

Answer (score -1):

in cart.jsx
dispatch({
type: 'ADD_TO_CART',
item: { id:id, title:title, price:price, image:image, rating:rating }
})